# about m1 os using mysql account problem like "Access denied for user 'user02'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Tags: mysql

I tried to use mysql in anaconda venv environmment. but it occures problem like belows.

first, when I mysql-server start. it's result is successed but it says "mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists." but originally it gave me new terminal window that can works mysql query but now it doesn't give me that and I don't know how to check mysqld process is running or where it is.

second, to trying to check mysql, I tried to command 'mysql_secure_installation', then it says "Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"..... what is this situation? I didn't put any password, I just test 'mysql_secure_installation' but I don't understand why it occures.

third, I tried " mysqld --skip-grant" for accessing, but it says like below..

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Aside from that: this is off-topic here, as it's not a programming question. Maybe ask on [dba.se], [unix.se], or [su] (just check guidelines first).

Comment: As david said, this might be off topic. But, try running `ps -ef | grep mysql` command. And make sure you have created the user with permission to access from localhost. And search online, this is not really an unique problem.